# е сохраняется модель нейронной сети в keras. Ошибка AttributeError: 'Adam' object has no attribute 'get_slot_names'

Tags: python, keras

Не сохраняется модель нейронной сети в `keras`, сохраняю командой `model.save('progn')` и возникает ошибка

> AttributeError: 'Adam' object has no attribute 'get_slot_names'

Код не мой а с этого сайта, но сути это не меняет, ошибка та же.

```py
import numpy as np
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dropout, Dense

vec_size = 100
n_units = 10

x_train = np.random.rand(500, 10, vec_size)
y_train = np.random.rand(500, vec_size)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(n_units, input_shape=(None, vec_size), return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(n_units, return_sequences=True))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(LSTM(n_units))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(vec_size, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='adam')


model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5, batch_size=50)

model.save('progn')
```